# NGINX: Redirect only search-bots to a given file

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I try to port my previous .htaccess (used with apache) to nginx:

```
<IfModule rewrite_module>   
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond "%{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" "(Googlebot|bingbot|slackbot|vkShare|W3C_Validator)" [NC]
        RewriteRule .* bot.php [L]
        RewriteBase /
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule .* index.html [L]
    </IfModule>
```

Following is, what I currently try:

I have generate a map as List of SearchEngine:

```
map $http_user_agent $search_engines {
default 0;
"~bingbot.*" 1;
"~BingPreview.*" 1;
"~Googlebot.*" 1;
}
```

```
if ($search_engines = 1){
   rewrite ^/(.*) bot.php?$1 break;
}
```

But this creates an invinite Loop.

Here is the full server-block:

```
server {
    server_name mypage.de www.mypage.de;
    listen 1.1.1.1;
    root /home/mypage/public_html;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
    access_log /var/log/virtualmin/mypage.de_access_log;
    error_log /var/log/virtualmin/mypage.de_error_log;
        
    fastcgi_param GATEWAY_INTERFACE CGI/1.1;
    fastcgi_param SERVER_SOFTWARE nginx;
    fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
    fastcgi_param REQUEST_METHOD $request_method;
    fastcgi_param CONTENT_TYPE $content_type;
    fastcgi_param CONTENT_LENGTH $content_length;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /home/mypage/public_html$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $request_uri;
    fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_URI $document_uri;
    fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT /home/mypage/public_html;
    fastcgi_param SERVER_PROTOCOL $server_protocol;
    fastcgi_param REMOTE_ADDR $remote_addr;
    fastcgi_param REMOTE_PORT $remote_port;
    fastcgi_param SERVER_ADDR $server_addr;
    fastcgi_param SERVER_PORT $server_port;
    fastcgi_param SERVER_NAME $server_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_param HTTPS $https;
    location ~ \.php(/|$) {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/php-nginx/123123123123123123.sock/socket;
    }
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    listen 1.1.1.1:443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /home/mypage/ssl.combined;
    ssl_certificate_key /home/mypage/ssl.key;
    
    if ($blocked_bots = 1) {
        return 444; # Connection closed without response
    }
    if ($search_engines = 1){
        rewrite ^/(.*) /bot.php?$1 break;
    } 
    
    if ($scheme = http) {
        rewrite ^/(?!.well-known)(.*) https://mypage/$1 break;
    }
    
    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.html;
        auth_basic "Administrator’s Area";
        auth_basic_user_file /home/mypage/.htpasswd;
    }
    
    # Cache-Controll
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/manuallyInclude/cache-policy.conf;
}
```

**2nd Question:**
I have another mapped variarble for social_network bots.
Do I really need to add for each mapping an own if-clause like this:

```
    if ($search_engines = 1){
        rewrite ^/(.*) /bot.php?$1 break;
    } 
    if ($social_networks = 1){
        rewrite ^/(.*) /bot.php?$1 break;
    }
```

or is there an easier way to combine those to one rewrite-rule?

Comment: 1) Every normalized URI should be prepended with slash, you need to use `/bot.php?$1` instead of `bot.php?$1`. 2) To answer the question what exactly cause the infinite loop, you need to post your full nginx `server` block (of course you can omit the parts containing private information like server names, certificates paths etc.)

Comment: Please post the complete `server` block.

Comment: K, I've added the Server-Block. But I think what  @IvanShatsky suggest... to add the leading slash still solved it. Thanx a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering your second question, use an empty string instead of "0" on your `map` translations (and since the default `map` value is exactly an empty string, you can omit the `default` line at all):

```
map $http_user_agent $search_engines {
    "~bingbot" 1;
    "~BingPreview" 1;
    "~Googlebot" 1;
}
map $http_user_agent $social_networks {
    "~*facebook" 1;
    "~*twitter" 1;
}
```

and use concatenation of variables for the final condition decision:

```
map $search_engines$social_networks $is_bot {
    ""      "";
    default 1;
}

server {
    ...
    if ($is_bot) {
        rewrite ^/(.*) /bot.php?$1 break;
    }
```

Comment: An for other maps which also should redirect to bot.php I only need to add them in the if-brackets, right?!

Comment: Yes, condition will be evaluated as true if the result of concatenation will be non-empty string (however strings like `0`, `00` etc. will be evaluated as false).

Comment: My Virtualmin - validation check for the Config-File tells me that only have the variable, or have both as you described above is an error in my config :(

Comment: Sorry, you are right, but this one should work :) And your regexes can be optimized as I show in example, there is no need to add the `.*` part to check if the User-Agent string contains some specific word.

Comment: does your new Script means, if it's not seo_engine or social_networks, then it is by default 1 ? That would not fit my needb, because general request should be allowed. I have another list with "blocked_bots". So my need is to check for seo and redirect them... but if additional to that, it's not a blocked_bot, it should show the general page (means no redirect)

Comment: No, it means if it's not seo_engine or social_networks, the result of all the `$search_engines`, `$social_networks` etc. will be an empty string, the result of concatenation of the all variables will be an empty string too, and the resulting string `$is_bot` will be empty string too (see `""  "";` line). Otherwise (it it is search engine or social) that like won't passed a check, meaning the result will be exactly `1` (as it said by variable name, `is_bot`). How are you check the request to find is it a social network or not (how the `$social_networks` variable is defined in your config)?

Comment: search_engines and social_networks work like a charm, but prevent real bot's don't. 
Solve it now with this: ```map $blocked_bots $block_bot {
     ~*1     1;
     default 0;
 }```

Comment: You can short `~*1` to `~1`, digit chars are not case-sensitive :) And you can accept an answer if the solution is works for you :)